# if/else test if ANY row in a column is greater than an absolute value (R studio)

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean, boolean-logic

I'm trying to test if **any** value/row from the column `cooksd` is greater than absolute 1.

```
if (any(lev$cooksd) > abs(-1)) {
  print('yey')
} else {
  print('no') 
}
```

Warning message:

> In any(lev$cooksd) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical

but I don't think the `any()` function is doing the job...Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Obs:

the data looks like this: (first two rows)

```
cooksd mdffits covtrace covratio leverage.o~1
 <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
 0.0496  0.0478    0.0368     1.04        0.395
 0.0261  0.0251    0.0371     1.04        0.395
```

edited after comment:

```
if (any(abs(lev$cooksd) > 1)) {
  print('yey')
} else {
  print('no') 
}
```

Comment: Wrong parenthesis placement, try instead `any(lev$cooksd > 1)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas oh, yeah, thank you! I've also noticed that I've place the abs() in the wrong part as well (edited) thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler, more efficient and more informative to compute the maximum of the column values:

```
max(lev$cooksd) > 1
```

As well as showing you what the maximum value is, which might be informative, this approach is 3 to 4 times as fast as using any():

```
> x <- runif(1e8)
> system.time(any(x > 1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.47    0.01    0.49 
> system.time(max(x) > 1)
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14
```